# gradient background fade-out and going to another page

Tags: java, android, xml

I have page with gradient background and I also have an anim XML page to change the alpha from 1 to 0 ,I tried to fade out background and then go to another page but the problem is when  the duration finish (background fade out) and it want to go to another page background  for one second appear in screen.what can I do with this problem?

anim/fade_out.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="4000" >

</alpha>
```

drawable/linegradient.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:centerX="20%"
    android:endColor="#aed36c"
    android:startColor="#44c8f5" />

</shape>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/firstpage"
android:background="@drawable/linergradiant"

android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/texture" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_big2" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AnimationListener {
 LinearLayout screen;
// Handler handler = new Handler();
 int i;
 Intent intent;
 Animation animFadeout;
 Animation animFadein;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    screen=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstpage);
    animFadeout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out );

    animFadeout.setAnimationListener(this);

    screen.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            screen.startAnimation(animFadeout); 
        }
    }); 

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    animFadein=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in );
    animFadein.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BMIcalculator.class)); 

        }
    });
     screen.startAnimation(animFadein);

}
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}

}
```

Comment: You mean wait 1 second after the animation is done and start activity?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin no I mean after background fade out then for 1 second background show completely, and then go to next page .

Comment: so after the background is transparent you want it to be non transparent again?? and go to another activity

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes exactly !

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I find the answer.I guess maybe u want to know the answer ;) thx

Comment: Glad you solved it. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer how can I solve this problem 
it can solve easily by adding

```
animFadeout.setFillAfter(true);
```

it works very well right now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **fade_in** animation to reverse the effect of the **fade_out** animation

create a **fade_id** animation in your anim folder

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" >
</alpha>
```

use this after the animation of the **fade_out** is completed using the `onAnimationEnd` of it.

**sample:**

```
 @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in );
        animFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { 
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BMIcalculator.class)); 
            }
        });
        screen.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
     }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, now after fading out, background show again and stop. it doesn't go to next page.

Comment: @mimi I got a typo sorry. change this `animFadeout.setAnimationListener` to `animFadeIn.setAnimationListener` insinde the `onAnimationEnd`

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin I changed it as u said but first the background fade out then fade in and after that go to next page.

Comment: @mimi it is not working?? So you want it to first fade_out and then fade_in then change activity.. Am I right?

Comment: I update my code u can see it. I did exactly as u said but it didn't answer,background fade out and in then go to next page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59227/discussion-between-mimi-and-rod-algonquin).